# Reference - Heidegger on Hölderlin's translations?

Tags: heidegger, translation, poetry, greeks

Surely Heidegger was well aware of the enormous power of Hölderlin's translations,  especially of Sophocles' tragedies. Did Heidegger write something about this facet of Hölderlin?

Comment: See e.g.[Heidegger on Hölderlin](https://www.pdcnet.org/pdc/bvdb.nsf/purchase?openform&fp=philstudies&id=philstudies_1973_0022_0000_0007_0016).

Comment: And see Martin Heidegger [Erläuterungen zu Hölderlins Dichtung (1936-1968)](http://www.klostermann.de/Heidegger-ErlzHoelderlin-3AuflLn) translated as [Elucidations of Hölderlin's Poetry](https://books.google.it/books?id=DnYpAAAAYAAJ&q=heidegger+Elucidations+of+H%C3%B6lderlin%27s+Poetry&dq=heidegger+Elucidations+of+H%C3%B6lderlin%27s+Poetry&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi16d2mo_3MAhUHWRoKHbVND2AQ6AEIHDAA) (2000).

Comment: And see [Hölderlin's Hymn "The Ister"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lderlin%27s_Hymn_%22The_Ister%22).

Answer (score 2):

In The Ister lectures (p. 56, GA 53 p. 70) Heidegger refers to Hölderlin's translation of *Antigone*, and continues through that chapter.